# Do PWM DC motor controllers need a cooling fan?

Tags: motor, dc

I just bought a DC 9-60V 20A, 1,200 watt motor controller. It will control a 48V 350 watt brushed DC motor. All the controller components are in a totally closed enclosure. Do these type of controllers generate heat? Should I have a small DC fan blowing on it to extend its life?

Comment: What does the user manual or datasheet say?

Comment: The manufacturer does not provide a datasheet or manual for this product.

Comment: @henrylr If the manufacturer does not provide something as essential as a datasheet, how confident are you that it will not catch fire or explode?

Comment: Maybe but probably not. However, it is best to test the motor controller using it the way you intend to and keeping track of temperature to see if it seems to be getting excessively hot. Also, if you were to put the controller inside something, another box or a small room with poor circulation, then you may need a fan for the controller or the box that it is in to maintain reasonable ambient temperature.

Comment: Is it [this one](https://www.amazon.com/9-60V-Regulator-Controller-Control-Driver/dp/B07PQP8ZYG)?

Answer (score 2):

The controller is rated for 20 amps and the motor appears to require no more than about 10 amps. The heat dissipated in the controller is, to a great extent, proportional to output current. If it does not appear to be designed for use with a cooling fan, you probably don't need one. However a controller sold without documentation can not be assumed to be a well-designed, good-quality product. From that point of view, it might be a good idea to add a fan or at least carefully monitor the temperature and be prepared to add a fan if the temperature seems too high.

A good controller will limit the accelerating current and provide reasonably good motor performance at reduced speeds. The torque capability should remain constant over the speed range. However the motor probably depends on its own motion to help dissipate its losses. It may overheat if operated at full torque and reduced speed for an extended period of time. You may need a fan for the motor more than for the controller.

Comment: Torque capability is greater at lower speeds because motors make a back-emf voltage, proportional to shaft speed, which limits current into motor coils, and this reduces torque at higher speed. Brushless (BLDC) controller may be designed to hold torque constant at lower RPM but as the RPM goes up to the point where it intersects the torque-speed curve then the motor will make less torque as speed increases according to the slope of the torque-speed line.  Brush motor controller could use feedback to produce constant torque however the controller in question probably does not do so.

Comment: Even a cheap junk speed controller probably has a current limiter for its own survival. If it doesn't, you will soon need to replace it and perhaps the motor as well. What @SystemTheory describes is more like a motor connected to a battery with an on/off switch. That works for small, inefficient motors, but not likely to be suitable for a 350 W motor.

Answer (score 1):

> Do these type of controllers generate heat?

Yes.

> Should I have a small DC fan blowing on it to extend its life?

It always helps solid state electronics to keep them cool. Whether forced air cooling is mandatory depends on the particular circuit and the power it dissipates  ( not the power it delivers).

Answer (score 0):

I would say no the typical motor speed controller does not require a cooling fan. Online vendor(s) show a unit in a metal case with the following description:

DZS Elec DC Motor Controller 9-60V High Power PWM Control Switch Motor Speed Regulator DC 12V 24V 36V 48V 60V 20A 1200W

Video Review of 20A DC 10-60V PWM Motor Speed Controller:

https://youtu.be/kgs_FILyppk

Video DC Motor Controller with Current Limit and Schematics:

https://youtu.be/AukuGUcS3Bk

The power electronic devices, which are designed to pass high current at rated voltage, should have heat sinks (often attached to the metal case if a case is provided). I am not aware of whether such units use self-protection circuitry to protect the power electronic devices and/or motor coils. An external fan should not be necessary and likely would not extend the operating life of internal components provided with proper thermal design and/or thermal self-protection.

This video shows the speed-torque curve for a PMDC motor:

https://youtu.be/pxtRlKs0pAg

Sometimes the data are given as a torque-speed curve with torque on the vertical axis and speed on the horizontal. Notice the no load speed is voltage divided by motor torque constant. Notice the stall torque is proportional to voltage, torque constant, and inverse of the coil resistance. This means when you PWM 100% the average voltage is greater and the curve moves away from the origin. If you PWM at less than 100% then the average voltage decreases and the whole curve moves toward the origin as PWM goes toward 0%. The motor must be able to accelerate the load through the maximum power point in a short period of time, and then spend most of its time operating well below its maximum power potential, in order to minimize heat dissipation in the motor coils.

The PMDC motor can be destroyed by operating for too long outside its safe operating area (SOA). In general a PMDC motor takes maximum current, and makes maximum torque, when driven at its maximum voltage rating starting from zero revolutions per minute (RPM) or zero radian per second (rad/s) angular shaft speed. So PWM would be 100% with the motor starting a load or stalled shaft and this puts the most thermal stress on the electronics and motor windings. If this stall current persists it will increase the winding temperature and melt the varnish on the wires that preserves the integrity of the motor/generator winding coils.

Using this reference:

http://lancet.mit.edu/motors/motors3.html

You want the motor and speed controller to be able to accelerate the mechanical load up to speed so the motor is not operating at high current, high torque, and low speed for significant periods of time. In other words when starting the load the motor must rapidly roll through the maximum power point and then produce less torque at higher speed to operate within its safe operating area for thermal dissipation. If the motor draws current under a heavy mechanical load then heat builds up in the thermal capacitance of the windings. Too much temperature degrades the varnish in the coils.

Comment: When the controller pot is turned down, reducing motor speed, is energy from the power supply dissipated, as heat, in the motor controller?

Comment: PWM less than 100% reduces the average voltage across, and current flowing through, the motoring coils. This is less power dissipation in the power electronics of the motor controller. However it means less torque available to drive the mechanical load so the motor and controller must be designed to drive the particular load without doing any damage to the motor when starting the load from a dead stop or under equilibrium speed or range of torque-speed (mechanical power output) operating conditions. Motor should have a datasheet with its maximum efficiency point within the safe operating area.

Comment: Reading about DC brushed motors I got the impression  that a brushed DC motor driven by a properly designed power supply and a PWM controller would maintain constant torque throughout the motor rpm range. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @henrylr I don't believe that you misunderstood.

Comment: I didn't understand the answer to my question: "When the controller pot is turned down, reducing motor speed, is energy from the power supply dissipated, as heat, in the motor controller?" It seems the power supply has no idea what the controller is doing and the motor just reacts to the power it gets. That leaves the motor controller to raise or lower power to the motor. Based on that it seems the controller is confronted with variations in heat generated by power reduction to the motor. Is that correct?

Comment: @henrylr a PWM controller will be reasonably efficient at low and high speeds.  It does not operate by wasting extra power as heat. The controller pot is probably just generating a control voltage for the PWM controller. The motor power is not flowing through the controller pot.

Comment: @henrylr No a PMDC (brush) motor does not maintain constant torque throughout the RPM range when driven by open loop PWM controller. A controller with feedback loop might be able to hold torque constant for a portion of the speed range but this would be well below maximum stall torque of the motor. Watch this video https://youtu.be/roINUVVpEbs the stall torque and stall current are very large. The no load current is very small (enough torque to keep motor spinning against friction). If PWM voltage it reduces current, torque, and speed but also reduces the mechanical shaft output power.

Comment: @SystemTheory: A DC motor should always be operated well below the stall torque. If the speed controller is worth having, it will limit the current to a level that is safe for the controller and safe for the motor. The result is a motor and controller system that has constant torque capability over a reasonable speed range. Note that the motor in question is a 350 W motor, not a toy.

Comment: @Charles Cowie The controller may or may not limit the torque (current) sent to a PMDC motor over the speed range and it cannot maintain constant torque over the entire range. So what I wrote here is accurate. Also I have provided an answer that makes it clear that the motor will be destroyed when operated at high current, high torque, and low speed either in an application where current is not limited, so the PMDC torque can be used to accelerate a load rapidly, or in an application where the controller limits the stall current. Either way the analysis of PMDC motor is via torque-speed curve.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to use a 350W motor, perhaps continuously. It's reasonable to assume 95% efficiency, so the power stage will dissipate a bit under 20W. Passive cooling may be fine if designed correctly-metal heat sink with fins.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to keep a motor controller too cool. Better to err on the side of overkill and add a fan (or 12).

I just installed a dual motor controller on my wheelchair motor powered brush mower and it got hot quick. Luckily, it's a Cytron MDDS30 (30a continuous running from 24 V, 40 Ah LiFePO4) so it has extreme thermal throttling built-in.

I should have sorted out some fan cooling beforehand, as it basically entered 'limp' mode which at times couldn't even turn the blasted thing.  For everyone reading this, save yourself the frustration. Design and add a cooling system beforehand!